# SharePoint 2013 Manage Access Request History

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, access-denied, auditing

I am requesting information on SharePoint 2013 Manage Access Request history.

1. How long is the history kept or is there a size / item limit?
2. Can you export the history? If so how?
3. Can the History be purged? If so how?
4. Is the history for all sites (in a given site collection) kept in a single area in the content database?
5. Any issues with using this info as an informal audit source?
6. Any MS documentation / links regarding the questions above?

Any info is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in a hidden list by the name "Access Requests", if I guess correctly there should be one in each site/sub site where permissions inheritance is broken.